# Aspose.Net and page numbers horizontal alignment

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I use Aspose.Word library in my project and I try to convert html to doc. I added page numbers with this code:

```
        var builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
        HeaderFooter header = builder.CurrentSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary];
        if (header == null)
        {
            header = new HeaderFooter(builder.CurrentSection.Document, HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary);
            builder.CurrentSection.HeadersFooters.Add(header);
        }

        builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);

        builder.PageSetup.PageStartingNumber = 1;
        builder.PageSetup.RestartPageNumbering = true;

        builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
        builder.InsertField("PAGE", string.Empty);
        builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
```

Page numbers are placed at the top left corner of their pages. Is it possible to place them at the right top corner? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use ParagraphFormat.Alignment property to get or set text alignment for the paragraph.

```
Document document = new Document(MyDir + "in.html");
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
HeaderFooter header = builder.CurrentSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary];
if (header == null)
{
    header = new HeaderFooter(builder.CurrentSection.Document, HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary);
    builder.CurrentSection.HeadersFooters.Add(header);
}

builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);

builder.PageSetup.PageStartingNumber = 1;
builder.PageSetup.RestartPageNumbering = true;

builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);

//Use following line to get the required output. 
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

builder.InsertField("PAGE", string.Empty);
builder.MoveToDocumentEnd();
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.